# Netlify "ng command not found"

Tags: angular, deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy my angular app on netlify. However, I am running into a problem where it says ng command not found. I have angular cli and npm globally on my computer. The current deploy settings are:

Build command: ng build --prod

Publish directory: dist/mysite

What could be the cause of this? Thanks a ton!

Here are the logs related to the failed build

```
5:43:56 PM: Build ready to start
5:43:58 PM: build-image version: 84aca9ba39e0ee86ba194760fbfc51a808f62543
5:43:58 PM: buildbot version: 57d44fd1631cc3fff8b38fbaf88d3d04f946418a
5:43:58 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
5:43:58 PM: Starting to download cache of 254.7KB
5:43:58 PM: Finished downloading cache in 113.606368ms
5:43:58 PM: Starting to extract cache
5:43:58 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
5:43:58 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
5:43:59 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
5:43:59 PM: git clone git@gitlab.com:jshede/my-website
5:44:05 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
5:44:08 PM: Starting build script
5:44:08 PM: Installing dependencies
5:44:09 PM: Downloading and installing node v8.15.0...
5:44:09 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.15.0/node-v8.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
5:44:10 PM:   0.0%
5:44:10 PM: 
###################
5:44:10 PM:                                              26.9%
5:44:10 PM: 
#####################
5:44:10 PM: ################################################### 100.0%
5:44:10 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
5:44:10 PM: Checksums matched!
5:44:13 PM: Now using node v8.15.0 (npm v6.4.1)
5:44:13 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
5:44:14 PM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
5:44:14 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
5:44:14 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
5:44:14 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
5:44:14 PM: unset GOOS;
5:44:14 PM: unset GOARCH;
5:44:14 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64';
5:44:14 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
5:44:14 PM: go version >&2;
5:44:14 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.10.linux.amd64.env';
5:44:14 PM: go version go1.10 linux/amd64
5:44:14 PM: Installing missing commands
5:44:14 PM: Verify run directory
5:44:14 PM: Executing user command: ng build --prod
5:44:14 PM: /usr/local/bin/build: line 32: ng: command not found
5:44:14 PM: Caching artifacts
5:44:14 PM: Started saving pip cache
5:44:14 PM: Finished saving pip cache
5:44:15 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Started saving go dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
5:44:15 PM: Cached node version v8.15.0
5:44:15 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
5:44:15 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:44:15 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
5:44:15 PM: Finished processing build request in 17.582066584s
```

Here is my package.json in angular app

```
   {
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^5.11.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.14.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^21.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you set the base directory? what is your netlify build command (ng build --prod)? in your repo, the root is not the root of the project so netlify cannot see your package.json unless you set the base directory

Comment: try using `npx ng build --prod` in case angular-cli is not globally installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some `Angular` simple setup settings I use on `Netlify`

### Ignore dependencies and deploy folder

No need to keep these in your repo. Netlify will spin up the correct tooling and add your dependencies.

`.gitignore`

```
/node_modules
/dist
```

### Setup your build environment for Netlify (optional)

A `netlify.toml` overrides the settings on the app.netlify.com admin, so I don't have to edit them if I want a change. They can be set there without this file.

`netlify.toml` (root of repository)

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build:prod"
  publish = "dist"
```

#### Add the `build:prod` to the scripts section of `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

### Setup correct deploy location in `angular.json`

`projects.mysite.architect.build.options.outputPath` should be "dist" or something unique and match your `netlify.toml` publish value and the ignore path. (**note:** it is ok to use subpaths as long as they all match like dist/my-site)

### Make sure to have a `_redirects` to handle the SPA

`projects.mysite.architect.build.options.assets` value should look similar to the following in the `angular.json`

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/_redirects"
        ],
```

Create the redirects file with following at a minimum to proxy our routes to the root index page.

`src/_redirects`

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Comment: Yeah, once you start to realize how Netlify is just the same as doing a production build just like you would on local and serve up your local publish directory, things will get clearer. As best practice, I use `serve <directory>` to test my builds prior to committing for a netlify deploy.

Comment: It worked for me. Until I tried adding the redirects. Although the file is included in my Netlify deployment build. Netlify does not find my redirects for some reason.